# Tokens in Places invisible

Tags: jointjs, petri-net

Since JointJs 2.0.0 (this also occurs in 2.0.1) the PetriNet Plugin does not render any tokens in the places.
The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Josch_hh/bjkqaLwx/1/) contains the demo from the JointJS site with the newest JointJS version.

The following code should create a place with one token, but no token is rendered. When the JointJs version is changed to 1.1.1, the tokens are rendered.

```
var pReady = new pn.Place({
    position: {x: 140, y: 50},
    attrs: {
        '.label': {text: 'ready', fill: '#7c68fc'},
        '.root': {stroke: '#9586fd', 'stroke-width': 3},
        '.tokens > circle': {fill: '#7a7e9b'}
    },
    tokens: 1
});
```

How can I render the tokens in the places?